# Javascript array to multi level Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an array in JavaScript and need to convert it to multi-level object.
Example:
Input :

```
var myArray = ["abc", "def", "ghi"] ;
```

Output I want :

```
var myObj = {abc:{ def: { ghi: {} } }};
```

What is most efficient way to achieve it with JavaScript ?

Comment: Can you show us your "inefficient" way and maybe we can improve it?

Comment: The way this is written it sounds more like a request for free code writing, not help with **your code**. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service but if you show your attempts and research efforts will get plenty of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` and pass empty object as accumulator.

```js
var myArray = ["abc", "def", "ghi"] ;
var obj = {} 

myArray.reduce((r, e) => r[e] = {}, obj);
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Why it won't work if you just assign the whole reduce function to a variable? Like `var res = myArray.reduce((..) => ..., {});`?

Comment: I think its because the last thing reduce returns is this `(r[e] = {})` which is equal to this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1796/

Comment: You could drop the `||`, since you know you're always operating on an empty object. `myArray.reduce((r, e) => r[e]={}, obj);`

Comment: It sounds logical. Btw, @squint, are you able to explain me also why if we assign the reduce function to a variable, it won't work? is it about what Nenad said?

Comment: @Kind user Just to make it clear, we are using obj as accumulator but you are assigning result of reduce to a variable which is the last returned thing from reduce as you can see here  https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1797/

Comment: @Kinduser: Yeah like Nenad said, the final value of `.reduce()` is the value you returned from the last invocation of the callback. Since each call returns the most deeply nested object, that'll be the final result. Holding the original object in a variable like he's doing is probably the cleanest way to handle it.